# Assign event handlers to an object instance at runtime in a generic way

Tags: .net, events, event-handling, generics

I'm trying to create a generic method which assigns (and deassigns) an event handler to an object instance's event at runtime.

Something like:

```
private void MyMethod<TEventArgs>(...)
   where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   EventHandler<TEventArgs> eventHandler = (s, e) =>
   {
      // logic
   }

   // want to assign eventHandler to an object instance passed into this method

   // more logic

   // want to deassign eventHandler from object instance
}
```

Currently, I'm passing in an assignEvent and deassignEvent delegate, something like:

```
private void MyMethod<TEventArgs>(Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> assignEvent, Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> deassignEvent)
{
   EventHandler<TEventArgs> eventHandler = (s, e) =>
   {
      // logic
   }

   assignEvent(eventHandler);

   // more logic

   deassignEvent(eventHandler);
}
```

And then calling the method like so:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
MyMethod<MyEventArgs>(e => myObject.MyEvent += e, e => myObject.MyEvent -= e);
```

This just seems really horrible though!

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potentially better option here is to convert this to an `IObservable<T>`, via using [Observable.FromEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff403047%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (in the Rx Framework).  This allows you to treat the event itself in a first class manner,  pass it into your method, then `Dispose()` the subscription at the end.

Comment: While using `IObservable<T>` is arguably a better pattern, it's syntactically similar; you still have to pass an action to `FromEvent` that can attach (and detach) a given handler.

Comment: @Adam: I was thinking more along the lines of this being a common issue in the OP's code, in which case this can be done one time, up front, and reused, since the `IObservable<T>` can then be passed around...  But yes, the initial creation, if working from an event, is very similar.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I might explore this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a much cleaner option. Events, despite being usable within the declaring class as an ordinary delegate member, are not publicly exposed as delegates. The `event` keyword means that it exposes `add` and `remove` functionality, but nothing else. In other words, you can't just pass `myObject.MyEvent` to `MyMethod` (unless you were to expose the actual delegate, which is a bad idea).